Interior, boundary, derivate and closure of Intersection, union and product of sets
Assume the standard topology over $\mathbb{R}$ for this question.
I also use:

$\text{int}$ for the interior of a set;
$\overline{A}$ for the closure of a set;
$\partial$ for the boundary of a set;
$A'$ for the derivate of a set (the set of limit points).

I was trying to check, though examples, if the following relations are true or false.
$$(1)\qquad \text{int}(A \cup B) = \text{int}(A) \cup \text{int}(B)$$
$$(2)\ \color{red}{False}: \qquad \text{int}(A \cap B) = \text{int}(A) \cap \text{int}(B)$$
$$(3)\qquad \text{int}(A \times B) = \text{int}(A) \times \text{int}(B)$$
$$(4)\qquad \overline{(A \cup B)} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$
$$(5)\ \color{red}{False}: \qquad \overline{(A \cap B)} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$$
$$(6)\qquad \overline{(A \times B)} = \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$$
$$(7)\qquad (A\cup B)' = A' \cup B'$$
$$(8)\qquad (A\cap B)' = A' \cap B'$$
$$(9)\qquad (A\times B)' = A' \times B'$$
$$(10)\qquad \partial (A\cup B) = \partial A \cup \partial B$$
$$(11)\ \color{red}{False}: \qquad \partial (A\cap B) = \partial A \cap \partial B$$
$$(12)\qquad \partial (A\times B) = \partial A \times \partial B$$
I made some example with $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = (0, 1)$. I noticed that for example the boundary of intersection is not the intersection of boundaries, indeed $\partial(\mathbb{Q}\cap (0, 1)) = [0, 1]$ whereas $\partial \mathbb{Q} \cap \partial (0, 1) = \{ 0 ; 1 \}$.
Do you know some reference where to find detailed discussions for these identities? I can't go on by examples...
EDIT
Ok, by some example I found two counterexamples for the relations $(2)$ and $(5)$. Indeed take $A = (0, 1)$ and $B = (1, 2)$ then
$$\overline{A} = [0, 1] \quad \overline{B} = [1, 2] \quad \overline{A\cap B} = \emptyset \quad \text{but}\ \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \{ 1 \}$$
And
$$\text{int}(A) = A \quad \text{int}(B) = B \quad \text{int}(A \cup B) = [0, 2] \quad \text{but}\ \text{int}(A) \cup \text{int}(B) = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2)$$

In your example, $\text{int}(A\cup B)\ne (0,2)$

$int$ must be open, so you can't have $int(A\cup B)=[0,2]$.


$\text{int}(A\cup B) = \text{int} (A) \cup \text{int} (B)$ is False. For instance, take $A = [0,1/2]$ and $B=[1/2,1]$.
$\overline{(A\cap B)} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ is False. For instance, take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B =\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
$\partial (A \cup B) \neq \partial A \cup \partial B$ is False. Take $A = [0,1/2]$ and $B=[1/2,1]$ again.
$\text{int}(A\cap B) = \text{int} (A) \cap \text{int} (B)$ is True. More generally, in any topological space the interior of finite intersection equals the intersection of interiors.
$\text{int}(A\times B) = \text{int} (A) \times \text{int} (B)$ is True. More generally, in any topological space the interior of Cartesian product is the product of interiors.
$\overline{(A\cup B)} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is True. More generally, in any topological space the closure of finite union equals the union of closures.
$\overline{(A\times B)} = \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ is True. More generally, in any topological space the closure of product equals the product of closures.

Based on this,  try to tackle the remaining ones: specifically, (7), (9), (11), and (12). This type of exercise is best approached by working through the proofs and constructing counterexamples yourself, rather than searching for references. Any lingering questions can likely be resolved with the resources already available online.

Thank you so much for this. It'll be a starting point for my work!

You're welcome. Keep it up!
